# How to install prosody.im from source on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, lua, makefile

Because of this problem on Mac OS X with Lua 5.1: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/32354, I need to install prosody (XMPP server) from source (http://prosody.im/downloads/source/)

When I type "make" at the terminal, I get the error

> *** No rule to make target `config.unix'.  Stop.

I know very little about installing anything from source. I believe I have all the dependencies installed already, but I don't know how to get past this initial error.

Comment: You need to run `./configure` first.

Comment: duh, thanks. now running down Lua 5.1 problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run *only* Lua 5.1 via Homebrew, follow these steps:

**1. Prerequisites:**

Remove existing (conflicting) Lua 5.2 packages, i.e:

```
brew uninstall lua luarocks
```

**2. Install Luarocks via custom formula**

```
brew install https://gist.githubusercontent.com/DomT4/bc1e58d8237806b23464/raw/8e9ea37e73eaac8b8c7f18082de86891456cdad3/luarocks.rb --with-lua51
```

Note that this will also install the Lua 5.1 package given it is a dependency

**3. Install specific Luarocks packages**

These packages are required for Prosody

```
luarocks install luasec
luarocks install luasocket
luarocks install luaevent
luarocks install luaexpat
```

**4. Running Prosody**

Assuming you have configured it per Prosody documentation

```
lua5.1 prosody
```

**NOTE:** if you can create a link so that `lua` refers to `lua5.1` to save a lot of hassle as follows

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/lua5.1 /usr/local/bin/lua
```

---

**Final notes**

Be careful installing other homebrew formula which are dependent on the Lua or Luarocks formula, as you may break your existing Lua 5.1 installation

Comment: Thank you. When I run `lua5.1 prosody` (with 0.9.5 installed), I get the error `env: lua: No such file or directory`

Comment: If started again, this time, installing prosody via the Homebrew link on prosody.im, then followed your instructions. This time the error is `lua5.1 prosody
lua5.1: cannot open prosody: No such file or directory`

Comment: `lua5.1 /usr/local/Cellar/prosody/0.9.5/bin/prosody` runs, but prosodyctrl doesn't work

Comment: It is because there is no `lua` binary in your `/usr/local/bin`. To fix that, run `ln -s /usr/local/bin/lua5.1 /usr/local/bin/lua`. I've updated the answer to include that step

Comment: After doing that, prosody runs from command, but in logs: `Error initializing module 'posix' on 'localhost': error loading module 'util.pposix' from file '/usr/local/Cellar/prosody/0.9.5/lib/prosody/util/pposix.so':
 dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/prosody/0.9.5/lib` - whole log output: http://pastebin.com/vpCNwRF7

Comment: I had forgotten to set `./configure --ostype=macosx` - thanks Stu

Comment: --with-lua-include=/usr/local/Cellar/lua51/5.1.5/include/lua-5.1/

Comment: This saved me, thanks @StuartCarnie. I don't understand why lua installation is so broken on homebrew. I was just about to manuall instally everything myself.